# How to differentiate Action or Method in Symfony's controller

Tags: php, symfony, naming-conventions

When I have to create methods in a **Symfony Controller** I add the suffix `Action` in all the methods of the controller by convention.

But I want to ask, which is the *rule* to add `Action` suffix?

If a function does not return any *layout* or *response* is still an `Action`?

Example:

```
// src/AppBundle/Controller/BlogController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class BlogController extends Controller
{
  public function showAction($slug)
  {
      // ...
      return $this->render("foo.html.twig")
  }

  public function eraseElement($element)
  {
      // ...
      return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, it **is** an action. It is an action in terms of being bound to some URI pattern, and being called if you try to load that URI. But at the same time it is an **invalid** controller, because symfony controllers **MUST** return a response. If they don't you'll have a error like this:

```
Error: The controller must return a response (true given).
```

What about the `Action` suffix - it is essential if you use `YAML` routing with `b:c:m` format, because the method won't be recognized as an action at all otherwise. You may have a method without a suffix if you use `Annotations` routing, but it's still a best practice to add "Action", even though it's not required.

For more information, read the links below:

- [Symfony Routing](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html)
- [Controller](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html)
- [Best Practices /
  Controllers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/controllers.html)

Answer (score 4):

in the symfony best practices you can read this:

> The first Symfony versions required that controller method names ended
>   in Action (e.g. newAction(), showAction()). This suffix became
>   optional when annotations were introduced for controllers. In modern
>   Symfony applications this suffix is neither required nor recommended,
>   so you can safely remove it.

And on modern Symfony Applications, using annotation is a best practice:

> In addition, using annotations for routing, caching and
>   security simplifies configuration. You don't need to browse tens of
>   files created with different formats (YAML, XML, PHP): all the
>   configuration is just where you need it and it only uses one format.

[the link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/controllers.html)